# 1.5 to 9 V transistor boost converter issue

Tags: transistors, dc-dc-converter, oscillator

I'm working on a small boost circuit to power a 9 V device with one AA battery (power requirement is 9 V ~ 10 mA).
My circuit is inspired by the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIUZA0W26LA) - schematic can be seen in the beginning. I fully understand that such a design is not efficient but efficiency is not an issue for me.

I've simplified the schematic a bit and it looks like this in LTspice:

[image: LTspice simulation of discrete boost converter]

The simulation works fine and **Vprimary** can supply up to 40 mA without decrease in voltage.

In real life this circuit has two issues:

1. It does not reliably start upon connecting a battery (a quick shorting of emitter and base of Q3 starts it).
2. Supply voltage is only stable up to 3 mA (measured with potentiometer and ammeter) and decreases substantially after that. At 5 mA load output voltage is ~ 5.6 V.

Could somebody please give me improvements idea for this circuit to fix these issues?

**Edit: Here are the measurements from the assembled schematic @15mA load with updated schematic:**

[image: Updated Schematic]

[image: VPrimary]

[image: NPN Collector]

[image: PNP Base]

[image: NPN Base]

Comment: Place a resistor (22k, 47k, etc.) across the B-E of Q3 and see if "1" is fixed.

Comment: What's your inductor saturation current?

Comment: @RohatKılıç it does! Thank you!

Comment: @winny it is handwrought like this [link](https://ibb.co/jGxd81j)

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a step-up regulator IC?

Comment: @TonyM Curiosity - I would like to understand why this circuit does not work for me as expected while I am waiting for delivery of step-up regular IC.

Comment: Air core? What's your measured inductance?

Comment: @winny Can't measure it at the moment. I've replaced the handwrought inductor with [RLB0912-221KL](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/RLB-972764.pdf). It does seem to work better - Voltage drops to 7.6 V @ 10mA. Maybe the inductance was too large - can that affect the circuit in this case?

Comment: 85 mA saturation current on that guy. Should do the job. Please simulate your circuit with different value of inductance to find out.

Comment: @winny LTspice simulation does not produce output at all with 220uH inductance. Vprimary=Vin.

Comment: @winny reducing resistor across the B-E of Q3 to 5k worked. Circuit now simulates with 220uH inductor. However max current output is still around 10mA in real life and up to 40mA in LTspice.

Comment: What if you add DCR for the inductor and ESR to the battery to better model real life? If it doesn’t start oscillating in SPICE, try disabling initial point calculation, force a node with .ic statement or similar.

Comment: @IvanDemyachenko I'm confused. Where's the specific feedback that controls the output voltage? The output voltage isn't placed within a closed loop and that means to me a load-dependent output voltage.

Comment: @jonk it is controlled by Zener diode 1N4739

Comment: @IvanDemyachenko Thanks. Didn't notice that. R2 may be too big. You probably need some serious 'yank' going on with that zero and 1k seems weak. (You could also increase C2 but decreasing R2 is much better, I think.) Maybe 150 Ohm? And given a 10 mA load, do you really need that 100 uF? 22 uF should be fine. I might increase the base resistor R1, too. That seems excessively small (high base current) for what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The original poster may have since moved onto something different, but the information may still be helpful to others.**

It may be more practical building a simple flyback type converter as seen in the images below. It was constructed with a small 6 mm torroid and a BC817-40 as the switching device.
It is capable to deliver more than 10 mA at the required 9 V output. This type of circuit is not very efficient due to the low supply voltage and high peak currents.

The most difficult part may be winding the small torroid.

[image: Core size]

[image: Core specs]

[image: BC817-40]

[image: circuit diagram]

[image: Wave-forms]

Load step response.

[image: ILoad step]

Alternative option to control the output voltage. (Slightly more efficient)

[image: Option]

[image: Vout]

The simulation results agrees quite good with that of the actual test circuit.

[image: Test unit]

[image: Scope measurements]

The design showed no start-up problems during testing.

[image: Starting]

[image: Stop-start]

**Operation at 3.3 V**

Operating at this supply voltage, higher output voltages are possible after some modifications to the base resistor and zener diode value.

Results show achieving an output voltage of 15 V at 15 mA.

[image: 15 output]

[image: 15V at 15 mA]

[image: Scope 15V]

[image: 15V start]

**Reducing leakage inductance's.**

Moving past the initial proto stage, effort should be made to keep wires as short as possible in the final design.

[image: reducing leakage]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Although I've managed to get the original schematic working - it was not performing stably. I will definitely give your schematic a try.